# How to autostart j2me application on foreground?

Tags: java-me

I'm trying to make my j2me application to auto-start when the phone is powered on. (The phone is Sonim XP1301.)

I added jad attribute "MIDlet-Launch-Power-On: yes", and now application starts automatically but stays on the background... This is useless for me because the application is UI-based and requires user interaction...

Is there any other jad attribute that would force the application to start in *foreground*, or some j2me command to bring the application to foreground?

Edit: At Sonim developer site I found this:

"We have our emulator library in which you can check whether the application is in background. Once you get the result you can bring it to foreground

JavaBackgroundMode.isRunningInBackground(Midlet m); is used to check whether the Midlet is in background. If it returns true then it means it is in the background.

JavaBackgroundMode.bringToForeground(this); is used to bring an app to foreground."

..But I have NO IDEA what this actually means... What "emulator library"? Where can I download it and how to use it? If I try just to add this line to my code:

JavaBackgroundMode.bringToForeground(this);

..NetBeans gives me error "Cannot find sybmol: Variable JavaBackgroundMode".

Any ideas?

Edit2: Tested "push registry", does not work. JAD file looks like this:

```
MIDlet-1: Contactless,,example.contactless.ContactlessDemo
MIDlet-Description: This is basic JSR257 Contactless Communication API demo.
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 7738
MIDlet-Jar-URL: Contactless.jar
MIDlet-Name: Contactless
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.read, javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.write, javax.microedition.io.Connector.http, javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry
MIDlet-Push-1: autostart://:, Contactless, *
MIDlet-Vendor: Oracle
MIDlet-Version: 1.0
Manifest-Version: 1.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of MIDlet-Launch-Power-On before. Had to Google for it to learn that it is a Sprint specific JAD attribute.

Try using the standard way of auto-starting a MIDlet: Using PushRegistry.

Add these two lines in your JAD file instead, and remove the MIDlet-Launch-Power-On attribute.

```
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry
MIDlet-Push-1: autostart://:,NameOfMIDlet,*
```

See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks but this does not seem to work with my phone. During installation phone gives error "Critical info mismatch (jad,..)" and stops installation. I'm not sure if I used correct syntax, though. I copied the content of .JAD file to my original question.

Comment: It looks right to me. You could try to type in the packagename instead, just to be sure, but after finding http://radiantsilverlabs.com/content/everything-you-always-wanted-know-about-auto-starting-midlets-were-afraid-ask I'm not sure it'll make a difference. I never knew there were so many ways of autostarting a midlet. I've always only used PushRegistry, and it's worked on most phones I've tried with.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle-MIDlet-Autostart: 1
Oracle-MIDlet-Restart: false
Oracle-MIDlet-Restart-Count: 10

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional answer to this question:

Every MIDlet that is started automatically needs to be configured via its jad file and the following properties:

- Oracle-MIDlet-Autostart: [0-5], autostart order. 0 means no autostart. For MIDlets with
  the same level the order is not defined.
- Oracle-MIDlet-Restart: [true|false], if true the MIDlet is automatically restarted if it terminates non gracefully, e.g. by an uncaught exception.
- Oracle-MIDlet-Restart-Count: [number], number of allowed MIDlets restarts before the
  whole module is rebooted